# Custom button with drawable, like facebook

Tags: android, button, android-custom-view

I have been all morning trying to do an custom shape like as facebook button like this:

[image: Facebook Login Button]

But I'm trying to do it customizable, so in the future I could change the icon for example, but I'm going crazy.

How I can make a button like this? Only the right part must be pressed, the left with the icon must be static although it will be pressed.

I have this for the left side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/gecas_blue"/>

            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
                android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>
            <size
                android:height="@dimen/bt_icon_size"
                android:width="@dimen/bt_icon_size"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/gecas_blue"/>
            <size
                android:height="@dimen/bt_icon_size"
                android:width="@dimen/bt_icon_size"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_input_add">
        <size
            android:height="@dimen/bt_icon_size"
            android:width="@dimen/bt_icon_size"
            />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And this for the right, but I know how to continue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/gecas_blue"/>

            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
                android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/gecas_blue"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is the most similar library that I've found.

[Flat Buttons](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button)

Comment: with two different shapes

Comment: use `android:drawable_left` for left part!

Comment: I've added the xml that I have. I have the 2 shapes, but I don't know how to merge it in a selector. :S

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/medyo/fancybuttons it almost fit what you try to do.